# call parameters between two different classes in java

Tags: java

I have two classes(in different file) and one main class. I want to use their methods and parameters (such as int) in other method but when I create each of them as new I faced `"java.lang.StackOverflowError".`

my purpose :
Main >create class1>go to class1 and send int to class2>do sth and return result as int to `class1` again and print the result.

```
public class Class1 {

    Class2 class2=new Class2();
    protected int b=4;
    public void start (int c)
    {
        class2.run(b);
        System.out.println("Numbber :"+c);
    }
}



public class Class2 {

    Class1 class1 = new Class1();
    protected int a=5;

    public void run(int b) {
        int c=b+10+a;
        class1.start(c);

    }
}


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class1 class1 = new Class1();
        class1.start(1);
        //enter code here

    }
}
```

Comment: You have circular reference here and `run` calls `start` and over way around.

Comment: `run` calls `start` which calls `run` calls `start` which calls `run` calls `start` which calls `run` calls `start` which calls `run` calls `start` which calls `run` calls `start` which calls `run` calls `start` which calls `run` calls `start` which calls `run` calls `start` which calls `run` calls `start` which calls `run` calls `start` which calls `run` calls `start` which calls `run` calls `start` which calls `run` calls `start` which calls `run` calls `start` which calls `run` calls `start` which calls `run` calls `start` which calls `run` calls `start` which calls...

Comment: @GBlodgett Great demonstration.

Answer (score 0):

You have circular reference between the method `run` from Class2 and the method `start` from Class1.

Answer (score 0):

Your `run` method calls `start`, which calls `run`, which calls `start`, which calls...

> my purpose : Main >create class1>go to class1 and send int to class2>do sth and return result as int to class1 again and print the result.

If this is your purpose just make a method to do what you want and then return the result:

```
public int foo(int b) {
    return b+10+a;
}
```

So that your `start` method will call `foo()` and do the necessary calculations and then `return` the results instead of calling the method again. However Java is pass by value, so you will have to resolve the results of `foo()` to your variable. However you can simply just print the results:

```
public void start (int c)
{        
    System.out.println("Number :"+ class2.foo(b));
}
```